# Can internal and external sorting/filtering be applied to ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grid, angular-ui-grid

I have requirement where there is two ui-grids in one page as shown in the below screenshot[image]

In **UI-Grid One**: Batch Charges should have its own **sorting/filtering** i.e. through

```
col.enableFiltering = true;
col.enableSorting = true; // (Typescript code)
```

**In Grid two** - for **Samples** and **Test name** column it should have its own filtering/sorting enabled.

But apart from this from `List Price` column to `Net Interco` column the filtering/Sorting should work based on the first grid. i.e.

If I sort the `List Price` then the corresponding column in the second grid should also get sorted. similarly, when I use the filter on `NBS Price` the corresponding column in the second grid should also get filtered based on the entered text in the filter text box in the first UI-Grid.

Let me know if this is **possible** ??.

I tried `sortChanged` method of the UI-Grid API registering it through `onRegisterApi` but it didn't work.

So my final Grid config for both these grids will look like

```
grid.enableFiltering = true;
grid.enableSorting = true;
grid.useExternalFiltering = true;
grid.useExternalSorting = true;
```

So my other question is will both `enableFiltering` and `useExternalFiltering` work for same UI-Grid.

Answer (score 0):

For the filter change you can use the filterChanged event (I use it and it works fine).  Put it in your onRegisterApi function:

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {

   gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function(....) {
     // Set some scope variable that both lists use for filtering
     $scope.someFilterValueBothListsLookAt = ......
   });

}
```

I have not tried sortChanged but I would guess it works in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I tried both filterChanged and sortChanged. As I am new to TypeScript I am not able to call onRegisterApi function. Can you let me know the syntax in TS.

Comment: Sorry, don't use TypeScript so don't know.